# Sagemaker Regex pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, amazon-sagemaker

In Sagemaker `validation:auc` metric monitor has the following regex

```
.*\[[0-9]+\].*#011validation-auc:([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?).*
```

that searches the logs and extracts the matching metrics. I have to log the metrics, so that, they can match the above regex. For this, I tried the following

`[2]#011validation-auc:+0.89`

Actually I have a list of AUC values like

`[2]#011validation-auc: [+0.89, +0.90]`

to be logged. I can't modify the regex as it is predefined by the AWS Sagemaker. How do I format my log entries, so that, they can match the above regex?

Thanks
Raj.

Comment: It needs a string like `[2]#011validation-auc:+0.89 text...`

Comment: Actually it is looking for `[2]#011validation-auc:+0.89 e+1` where the e+1 is optional. The problem what I have seen is the + is `[0-9]+` doesn't work. For example say I change it to `[0-9]` this works. But the limitation is I can change the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a SageMaker Training Job, if you are using the SageMaker SDK you can set [`metric_definitions`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html) in your Estimator object to set the metric's regex.

Kindly see this link for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/training-metrics.html#define-train-metrics

Comment: Yes, that is correct but Sagemaker SDK has this problem. https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/issues/121#issuecomment-653108771, as you can see the workaround suggested https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/issues/121#issuecomment-1025248921 is what I'm trying above.

Comment: However, I'm unable to decode the complex regex

Comment: Have you built and tested a regex using a tool that you can pick up the string. For example, https://regex101.com/?